# How do I detect animated GIFs, 360-degree videos or Instant Articles via Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, animated-gif, 360-degrees

Facebook launched recently few new content types (animated GIFs, Instant Articles and 360-degree videos). Is it possible to somehow detect these types via Facebook API? So far I did not found clue...

Answer (score 0):

This is to be detected through the creation of the feed content. You have to detect and wrap it into the fb tags for `<figure class="op-social">` The common way to detect and transform your post content is using regex. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/reference/social